# Check if user has two roles or more containing name/id - from array

Tags: discord.js

I've been making Discord bots for a while, however I'm kinda stumbling upon this one element where as i want to fetch every user on the server that has the role "RoleA"

For each of the users having RoleA - I want to check if they then have any two or more of the role ids in the following array:

`["232543645756","8989789789678","7567567567567","34534534534325"]`

I do know you can loop the users roles to check if he has `RoleID || RoleID`

-- However as I want this to expandable I want to define all the roles in an Array, and then loop the user through the array to see if they have 2 or more role IDs found in the array tied to them.

Meaning if UserA has `232543645756` - but not any of the others in the array, it returns exact `length === 1`.

If user in this case has multiple role ids found in the array example:
`232543645756 & 7567567567567` ... `345345345345 & 8989789789678` ... `345345345345 & 8989789789678 & 232543645756` etc (Multiple roles found in the array)

I want this to be fetchable by: `If length >= 2 (or length > 1)`

#### My question is now then

Is it possible to make a system like this? See if a user has multiple roles without having to define `role1 && role2 || role1 && role3 || role1 && role4 etc - as this will be very messy if that array expands with more ids`

Or is it possible to do something like `If (roleArray.includes(member.roles.has...).length > 1) { Code here }`

-- Or is this only possible by pushing all the users role IDs to an empty array, and then check if there is two or more matches out from the members.role.... id?

Comment: So you have a role (`RoleA`) which must match and also a list of roles where any two from that list must match. You also mention that you know you can count matches. If you prepend `RoleA` to that list of roles, you can iterate over the resulting list, counting matches. Once you reach three matches, you know that `RoleA` and two additional roles have matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Collection#filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter)

```js
// roles to check
let roles = ["232543645756","8989789789678","7567567567567","34534534534325"]
// all members with RoleA
const members = guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has("RoleA-id"))
// all members with RoleA and at least 2 other roles from the array
const validMembers = members.filter(m =>
  roles.filter(r => m.roles.cache.has(r)).length >= 2
)
```